# JellyBlast ROM on Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360L

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rom, samsung-galaxy-y

I have a Samsung Galaxy Y GT-S5360L, and I wanted to install a new ROM, [JellyBlast](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=31097873). The only problem is the download link is broken. I searched all over google for the download, but all the links are broken. Where can I get the download? (Does it still exist? If not, what are some Jellybean themed ROMs I can get?)

Comment: Have you checked [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)

Comment: Cool. But I specifically want JellyBlast, and all the places I seached (including XDA Developers Forum) had a broken link (or on XDA Forums a link removed by a mod)

Comment: Well, I didn't check all sources referenced there – it was rather intended as a starting point for your search :)